# sort and manage user data input based on time in android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am a beginner.
I want to create a personal financial accounting app.
In this app, all user monetary transactions are stored based on time.
The user can with telling time Understand the transactions of that time.But I do not know how to do this.
Should I use sharePreferences? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Query the db based on order by time descending

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume you want to build a local database to store this information, if so you would be better off using [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/) to build, store and query your database. The link outlines the implementation has a few examples to get you started

Comment: Do you have another source?
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/
It's not possible to enter this address for Iranians. We are banning the use of Google products.

Comment: Doing a quick search i found another link https://medium.com/@ajaysaini.official/building-database-with-room-persistence-library-ecf7d0b8f3e9 with a similar outline, but i'm not sure what would be accessable to you. Given your trying to code on android it may be difficult to access most sites that would outline this( if most sites linked to google products are blocked)